# Xilinx ISE, expression not globally static inside generic map

Tags: generics, expression, vhdl, xilinx

Is this allowed inside Xilinx ISE :  `generic map (record1.field1'length)` ?

Previously I have defined record:

```
type test_record is record

 field1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

 field2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

end record;

constant record1 : test_record := ((others => '0'),(others => '0'));
```

I get this error message:

> The actual value (Attribute name) associated with a generic must be a globally static expression.

Comment: You do not provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your question is off-topic. This is a distinction between SO and EESE ([Xilinx ISE, expression not globally static inside generic map](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270874/xilinx-ise-expression-not-globally-static-inside-generic-map)). . The error cannot be reproduced without assumptions that may not match your code and it's possible to construct an example from your snippets that is legal VHDL. Note that creating an MCVE can be benefiical in determining the problem.

Comment: The solution described by Xilinx is to use the new parser which is available for ISE 14.7.  [Stevan Stevanovic](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Virtex5-compile-error-HDLParser-3305-The-actual-value-Attribute/m-p/734367#M20028) provided a test case to Xilinx and they demonstrated it [compiles](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Virtex5-compile-error-HDLParser-3305-The-actual-value-Attribute/m-p/734371#M20029 "compiles") with their new parser (noting you haven't provided either an MCVE nor information about version of Xilinx tool or target device family).

Comment: That answer is included in the answer to your Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange question [Xilinx ISE, expression not globally static inside generic map](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270874/xilinx-ise-expression-not-globally-static-inside-generic-map).

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. Thank you.